# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

When I call any function in `python3.6`, I get the error below; however, it works fine in `python3.4`. Any idea? 
`import tensorflow as tf 
tf.Session()`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

> Here is my  System information

- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Debian 8.7
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: by pip3
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.7.0
- **Python version**: 3.6.5
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.0
- **GPU model and memory**: K80, 12 GB
- **Exact command to reproduce**:
  import tensorflow as tf 
  tf.Session()

Comment: You probably have a file in your directory named `tensorflow.py`

Comment: @miradulo well, there is nothing in the directory. In any directory or in jupyter I get same error.

Comment: What does `dir(tf)` show you?

Comment: @miradulo Almost nothing: `['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
` In python3.4 it provides the whole list of APIs,

Comment: @miradulo with the new version of `python3.6` my problem is solved. I removed my previous `python3.6` and installed the version. Then installed `tensorflow` and it works. Probably you can follow same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new version of `python3.6` my problem is solved. 
I removed my previous `python3.6` and installed the newest version. Then installed tensorflow through `pip` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the problem too.
Reinstall TensorFlow solve my ploblem.

```
  pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
  pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: did not solve problem, now I am getting DLL load failed: module not found

Answer (score 0):

It depends with the version of tensorflow you are using. Recent Tensorflow versions do not have the session object. Instead, the use a function 'tf.function()'